# Learning C++, looking for a clarification on this project from a book

Tags: c++, loops

The goal here was to create a program that found and output all the prime numbers between 1 and 100. I've noticed I have a tendency to complicate things and create inefficient code, and I'm pretty sure I did that here as well. The initial code is mine, and everything that I've put between the comment tags is the code given in the book as a solution.

```
// Find all prime numbers between 1 and 100

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int counter; // loop counter
        int count_two; // counter for second loop
        int val; // equals the number of count, used in division to check for primes
        bool check;

        check = true;

        for(counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++){
            val = counter;
                for(count_two = 2; count_two <= 9; count_two++){
                    if((val % count_two) == !(check)){
                        cout << val << " is a prime number.\n";
                }
          }
    }
    return 0;
}
// program didn't work properly because of needless complication; all that needs to be checked for is whether a number is divisible by two

/*
*********correct code***********
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    bool isprime;
    for(i=1; i < 100; i++) {
        isprime = true;
    // see if the number is evenly divisible
    for(j=2; j <= i/2; j++)
    // if it is, then it is not prime
        if((i%j) == 0) isprime = false;
        if(isprime) cout << i << " is prime.\n";
}
return 0;
}
********************************
*/
```

From what I can gather, I was on a reasonably correct path here. I think I complicated things with the double loop and overuse of variables, which probably led to the program working incorrectly -- I can post the output if need be, but it's certainly wrong.

My question is basically this: where exactly did I go wrong? I don't need somebody to redo this because I'd like to correct the code myself, but I've looked at this for a while and can't quite figure out why mine isn't working. Also, since I'm brand new to this, any input on syntax/readability would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn about your debugger and its single-step function.  Single step through your code, and watch as your program does what you told it.  Figure out how what you did is different from what you wanted, and fix that.

Comment: On style: It's usual for statements in the same block to be at the same indent level. For example, `val = counter;` and `for(count_two = 2; ...` are in the same block, but have a different indent level in your code. It's also usual to line-up braces so each block is clear. Your innermost `if` has its close brace in line with the `for`, which can be confusing when trying to read it. Editors suited to coding will allow you to specify the size of tabs to help you with indenting, and I also recommend the option to convert tabs to spaces (if available).

Comment: I just want to point it out to you about `Sieve of Eratosthenes`   

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

This is a standard technique to find large prime numbers. I do not want to post this as a answer as this is not exactly what you have asked in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. @Bill I'll try working that into a program as I go along, interesting read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is, your code says a number is prime if it is *divisible* by *any* of the numbers from 2 to 9. You'll want a `bool` variable somewhere to require that it's *all* and not *any*, and you'll also need to change this line:

```
if((val % count_two) == !(check)){
```

Since `check` = `true`, this resolves as follows:

```
if ((val % count_two) == !true){
```

and

```
if ((val % count_two) == false){
```

and

```
if ((val % count_two) == 0){
```

(Notice how the value `false` is converted to `0`. Some languages would give a compile error here. C++ converts it into an integer).

This in fact does the opposite of what you want. Instead, write this, which is correct and clearer:

```
if (val % count_two != 0) {
```

Finally, one thing you can do for readability (and convenience!) is to write `i`, `j`, and `k` instead of `counter`, `count_two`, and `count_three`. Those three letters are universally recognized by programmers as loop counters.

Comment: +1 on the divisible check, was going to say that in the comments above but you took care of that :)

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you guys are saying, thanks. If I'm getting it, the line reading:
    
`if((val % count_two) == !(check))`

says that if there's any nonzero value after the modulus operation (while running with count_two equal to any value 2-9) it immediately labels that as a prime number and outputs it? That would explain why I have the same number appearing a few times consecutively in the output.

Thanks for the other tip as well, the bool values and operators were mentioned in the chapter so I tried to include some but your way is much clearer.

Comment: @EvanCarlstrom I updated my answer to more clearly explain what's going on there

Comment: @nullptr, almost there. It should read: `As it is, your code says a number is prime if it is *divisible* by any of the numbers from 2 to 9.`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys - very good first impression of this site.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the points made above:

1. You seemed to think you didn't need to have 2 loops. You do need them both.
2. Currently, in your code, the upper range of the inner loop is in-dependent on the value of your outer loop. But this is not correct; you need to test divisibility up the the sqrt(outer_loop_value). You'll note in your "correct" code they use half of the outer_loop_value - this could be a performance trade off but strictly speaking you need to test up to sqrt(). But consider that your outer loop was up to 7, your inner loop is testing division all the way up to 9 and 7 is in that range. Which means 7 would be reported as not prime.
3. In your "correct" code the indenting makes the code harder to interpret. The inner for loop only has a single instruction. That loop loops through all possible divisors. This is unnecessary it could break out at the first point that the mod is zero. But the point is that the `if(isprime) cout << i << " is prime.\n";` is happening in the outer loop, not the inner loop. In your (un-commented) code you have put that in the inner loop and this results in multiple responses per outer loop value.
4. Stylistically there is no need to copy the counter into a new val variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, point #2 in particular pretty much nailed exactly what I needed here.